# Serve polymer from non-root path gives 404 on refresh

Tags: routes, polymer

I am serving my Polymer app, not from the root but from a subdirectory. I have set the `rootPath = '/subDirectoryName/'`. Then I call refer to pages as `<a href$=[[rootPath]]/page>Page Name</a>` which lands me to the right page. But now when I hit refresh, it shows 404.

I understand it is because it needs to be redirected to index.html, but I can't understand how to use it. I have tried using use-hash-as-path and it helped only when I was serving from the root.

Thanks.

Comment: have you used `.htaccess` file? If not, this is propably what you are looking for. This file redirects all paths to `index.html` (or any other specified file)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Although I wanted to confirm if this would be subdirectory specific, because there would be other directories which I don't want to alter in any way.

Comment: of course it will be. Lets say you have some root directory and subdirectory called `my-project`. Inside `my-project` directory you have this one specific project, where you have also `.htaccess` file. `.htaccess` file will only work in this subdirectory while all other sibling directories will remain untouched. Or, you can also specify which directories you want to redirect. So you can make exceptions

Comment: It doesn't seem to be picking up any changes. I've put `ErrorDocument 404 /index.html` in the .htaccess file (in my subdirectory) but it still ends up giving 404 error. I have deployed the app on Tomcat 8.

Comment: you have to have enabled modules on the server (if using rewrite rule). Actually, I am not using `ErrorDocument 404` (propably reduntant for me). Here is example of my `.htaccess`:  `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
RewriteRule .* /index.html [L]` .

Comments doesn't support new lines

Answer (score 0):

you have:

```
rootPath = '/subDirectoryName/'
```

AND

```
`<a href$=[[rootPath]]/page>Page Name</a>`
```

So the A tag will become

```
<a href$=/subDirectoryName//page>Page Name</a>
```

You are using double slashes. 
And you do not have quotes around your href.
Not sure if this is the problem though.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I made the corrections, but it didn't work. 

Finally got it to work by writing a rewrite.config file which is available in Tomcat 8 and upwards.